# How do I change name of 45000+ products via single import?

Tags: import, csv

I am working on one Magento Commerce store and **want to change name of 45000+ products via single import**. There are too many products on website with all CAPITAL product name.

This is creating big issue in Google merchant center data feed. So, I would like to make it proper via `CSV` import. I have compiled one CSV file which contain Product ID & Product Name with require format.

But, I am not able to import entire CSV file in Magento commerce Admin panel via Import / Export section. It shows me Time Out warning.

So, I have to split one CSV to multiple CSV files and continue this task. This is really frustrating to me. So, How do I change name of 45000+ products via single import?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question but it might be a solution to your problem.
If you want to transform the names of products from `PRODUCT NAME` to `Product name` you can do it with an sql update statement and not get tangled up in the Magento import process.
First you need to find the `id` of the name attribute.

```
select b.attribute_id, b.attribute_code from eav_entity_type a 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute b 
    ON a.entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id 
    AND a.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product' 
WHERE b.attribute_code = 'name'
```

In my case it was 71. 
Then run this query that updates the names.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
    SET `value` = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(`value`, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(`value` FROM 2)))
WHERE attribute_id = 71
```

Replace 71 with the id you get from the first query. Make sure you do a backup first.
Like I said, this only transforms titles from `PRODUCT NAME` to `Product name`. If you have brand names in the product name and want to keep them 'ucfirst' (PRODUCT NAME => Product Name) then ignore my answer.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for your valuable reply! I am going to try on my website. If I will find out any issue on it so I will let you know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Product name attribute value is stored in 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' table and you can update product names via query:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
SET `value` = CONCAT(
    UCASE(LEFT(`value`, 1)),
    SUBSTRING(`value`, 2)
)
WHERE
    attribute_id =(
        SELECT
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'name'
        AND entity_type_id =(
            SELECT
                entity_type_id
            FROM
                eav_entity_type
            WHERE
                entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
        )
    )
```

After this query you should do indexation on "product flat data":
`admin->System->Index Management` and click "Reindex Data" link on row "Product Flat Data".

Comment: 2 Subselects ? , use 2 join instead

Comment: @dweeves in that case subselect is more performance-able than the join.

Comment: it should not, as there should be indexes on each join field.However eav_entity_type & eav_attribute tables being small tables, maybe the join is a bit less performant.But here, 3 full selects instead a single with joins, my guess is JOIN should win

Comment: Everybody can write this solution more compact and with one line, but at this point I assumed an answer to be more understandable and simple. I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) , it is conceived to achieve such things (and many more).